# Insert array values and single form values into all rows PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

Could someone tell how to write this insert into a database? The below code is an example of what I am trying to accomplish. I want to have a form for families with multiple children. They submit their family names and one id that they will share in the database. See code below...

FORM INPUTS

```
<input type="text" name="fname[]"/>
<input type="text" name="lname[]"/>
<input type="text" name="fname[]"/>
<input type="text" name="lname[]"/>
<input type="text" name="family_id"/>
```

This is where I am having troubles. I can submit the family names but only the first(row) "name" is storing the "family_id" as well.

PHP

```
        foreach($_POST['fname'] as $key => $fname) {
            $lname = $_POST['lname'][$key];
                            $family_id = $_POST['family_id'][$key];

            $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO Table (FName, LName, Family_ID ) VALUES ('{$fname}', '{$lname}', $_POST['family_id'])"); 
        }
```

I appreciate any help!

Comment: Is family_id coming from database or it will be generated on this form submission?

Comment: it is coming from form submission.

Comment: What is the table structure? Is family_id a primary key? What is its data type?

Comment: the family_id is not a primary key. The primary is give to the individual person. According to your post below, do I need to make family_id into $family_id=family_id[$i]; ?

Comment: just saw your comment about microtime(). I am not familiar with that, how would you write it?

Comment: <input type="text" value="<?php echo microtime(); ?>" name="family_id"/>

Answer (score 0):

Missing `{}` around `$_POST['family_id']`.
`family_id` insn't an array.

So the first iteration you get

```
$_POST['family_id'][0]; // gets the id
```

The second

```
$_POST['family_id'][1]; // gets undefined index
```

To fix it do the following.

Add the following code before `foreach` loop and concat `$family_id` to the query like you did with the others.

```
$family_id = $_POST['family_id'];
```

Comment: I tried what you said but it still only inserts the id once. Is there a way to reset the pointer back to [0] for $family_id = $_POST['family_id']; before the foreach runs again?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
extract($_POST);
$total=count($fname);

for($i=0;$i<count($total);$i++)
{

$fname=$fname[$i];
$lname=lfname[$i];

 $query="INSERT INTO Table (FName, LName, Family_ID ) VALUES ('{$fname}', '{$lname}', $family_id)";

}
```

Comment: If it is not an auto-increment primary key, you can generate a rand id using function like microtime(), and store it while inserting.

Comment: I am going to try your code here, but dont I need '' around the post names like this...

Comment: $fname='fname'[$i] and $lname='lname'[$i]

Comment: I tried your code and got it to insert but only inserts one row. According to my form it should insert two names (two rows into database) and the one family_id.